# Set index of Kendo dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, kendo-dropdown

I know this question has been asked many times and there is so many links in Google. But my bad luck, nothing worked in my case.

I've a `Kendo dropdownlist` which I'm populating using `Json` data. The DB is sending this details based on **`Order by Name`**. So the `Index` in `dropdownlist` is **random** but ordered by names.

E.g.

```
<select id="ddlNames" data-role="dropdownlist">
<option value="-1">Select Names</option>
<option value="5 ">AAA</option>
<option value="9 ">BBB</option>
<option value="6 ">CCC</option>
<option value="3 ">DDD</option>
<option value="7 ">EEE</option>
<option value="4 ">FFF</option>
<option value="8 ">GGG</option>
<option value="1 ">HHH</option>
<option value="2 ">III</option>
</select>
```

I've to change the `Index` of this `dropdownlist` on click of a `button`.

```
 $.ajax({

    url: "Test.aspx/DDL_List",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
        var appenddata = "<option value = '-1'> Select Names </option>";

        $.each(results.Table, function (i, value) {
            appenddata += "<option value = '" + value.NameID + " '>" + value.Name + " </option>";

        });
        $('#ddlNames').html('');
        $('#ddlNames').html(appenddata);
        $('#ddlNames').kendoDropDownList();


    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }

});
```

On click of button, I'm using below code to set the `Index` of `Kendo dropdownlist`.

**Problem :** if the `result[0].NameID =1`, it is setting the name which is found on top of the list i.e `AAA` , but not based on **`Index`** which should be `HHH` . I tried both `Value` and `Select`

```
var ddlNames= $("#ddlNames").data("kendoDropDownList");

            if (result[0].NameID != null) {
                var iNameID = parseInt(result[0].NameID);
                ddlNames.value(iNameID);
               //ddlNames.select(iNameID);
            }
            else {
                ddlNames.value(-1);
            }
```

Please guide.

Comment: why dont u use this example http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource

Comment: you need to order a list before add to dropdownlist?

Comment: I dont need to order a list. I'm trying here to set the Index of `ddlNames`.

Comment: I've edited the problem statement if that was confusing.

Comment: why you dont use datasource property of dropdownlist?

Comment: Please suggest, if something wrong in the code, as I'm a beginner in Kendo

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (data) {
    var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);   
    $("#ddlNames").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.data(results);
}
```

try like this...